# How to deal with functions defined on arrays in C++

Tags: c++

Suppose I want to define a function in C++ like

```
int sort( int a[n], int n)
```

Where I want the function to do operations on an array without predefined length. How do I do it?

Comment: Despite what it looks like, that function doesn't take an array with a predefined length

Comment: It's not clear if you think this takes a specific length and you want it to take a variable length or the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make your function a template to give you a handle on the array's dimension:

```
template <size_t N>
int mysort( int (&a)[N] )
{
  /// access as a[n], where n is in range [0,N)
}
```

but a more idiomatic way, since it also works with standard library containers and dynamically sized arrays, would be to pass two iterators:

```
template<typename Iterator>
int mysort(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {  ... }
```

Then

```
int arr[] = {1,54,3,7,9,87};
mysort(arr);
mysort(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

Bear in mind I changed the name to `mysort` because the standard library has a famous algorithm called [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Note that `std::end` doesn't work very well with dynamically allocated arrays, cause arrays in C++ typically don't know their length.  (`std::end(real_array_not_a_pointer)` only works because the compiler saw you declare that variable as an array of a certain size.)  So you'd have to pass `begin` and `begin + size`.  But finding `begin + size`, of course, requires knowing `size` at some point.

Comment: @cHao Correct. Neither does the first option, of course.

Answer (score 5):

The most idiomatic way would be to define a function that takes two iterators:

```
template<typename Iter>
int sort(Iter first, Itera last);
```

When in Rome, do as the Romans do ("Rome" = standard library).

Answer (score 2):

The compiler ignores the size of the array parameter because when you pass an array to a function, it is converted into a pointer. In fact,

```
int sort( int a[], int n)
```

is equivalent to

```
int sort( int* a, int n)
```

The size of the array will not be known until run-time and should be passed as the second parameter.

Comment: It's not really equivalent. Unless `n` is constant expression declared previously, it's just invalid code.

Comment: @jrok I thought that the compiler would just ignore the specified size. I know that if you don't specify the size, then the two are equivalent...edited to show that instead.

Comment: You're correct that it ignores it, the problem was the point of declaration. `const int n = 5; int sort(int a[n], int n);` would be fine and it would behave as you said. Nitpicking a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need some way to determine the end of the array if you want to use that structure. Strings as char arrays, for example, use a null terminator. If you do not have a way to determine the end of the structure you will not be able to safely iterate over it.

The pointer approach will allow you to iterate over the array, but you won't be able to safely determine the end of the array while iterating.

```
int sort( int* arr )
{
    // do your sorting here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do exactly what you are asking for. I guess the closest would be to use a `std::vector<int>`

```
int sort(std::vector<int>& a)
{
    ...
}
```

`std::vector` supports all the usual array operations (`a[i]` etc.) plus a few more, like `a.size()` to get the size of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer:

```
int sort(int* a, int n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have some element that marks the end of the array. That's how most string operations work, the end of the string is marked by '\0'.

Ideally though, you would not pass a plain array but some higher level object like a `std::vector` or `std::array`.